Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing
I tried to add some png on 3d model using rtf(React Three Fiber).
Here is my code
import React from 'react';
import { Decal, useGLTF, useTexture } from '@react-three/drei';

export function MaleMannequin({ tattooImage, ...props }) {
    const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('models/male_mannequin.glb');
    const tattooTexture = tattooImage ? useTexture(tattooImage) : null;

    return (
        <group {...props} dispose={null} scale={[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]}>
            <mesh geometry={nodes.FinalBaseMesh.geometry} material={materials['default']} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
                {/* Apply the tattoo texture as a Decal */}
                    <Decal
                        position={[0, -0.2, 0.5]} // Adjust as necessary
                        rotation={[0, 0, 0]} // Adjust as necessary
                        scale={0.75} // Adjust as necessary
                        map={tattooTexture} 
                        polygonOffsetFactor={-1} // This can help with z-fighting issues
                    />
            </mesh>
        </group>
    );
}

useGLTF.preload('models/male_mannequin.glb');

It gives the following warning and doesn't render image on model.

Warning: Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing. Please notify the React team.

tattooImage comes from parent as props.
Any one who can help me?
I made another model and used Decal of React Three fiber. It renders image.
I'd like to add PNG or JPEG on a specific part of the model body.

I found a solution to display an image on surfaces. However, the warning still interferes with me.
